# How to declare an array with two parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am trying to make a simple form with typescript. I want to create an array of 'username password' each time I create a user.

```
export class Form{
username : string;
password : string;
isChecked : boolean;
arr: string[] = new Array();

constructor(){
    this.isChecked = false;
}

signup(){

this.arr.push(this.username);
console.log(this.arr);

}

submit(){
var res = document.getElementById('check');
res.innerText = String(this.isChecked);
}
}
```

This code works but only with username when I check on the console but I want something that gives me arr[0] --> username, password and not only the username for example. I know it is something with the declaration of arr but I try other ways to declare it and I always get stuck.

Comment: Are you trying to describe an array of a [**tuple type**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) e.g. `[string, string][]`? See http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20arr%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20string%5D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aarr.push(%5B'hello'%2C%20'world'%5D)%3B%0D%0Aarr.push(%5B1%2C%202%5D)%3B%0D%0A

Comment: do you actually want an 2D-array (array of array) ? like `[["username","password"]]` ? or maybe an array of object `[{username:"foo",password:"bar"}]` ?

Comment: please add a json example of the array. :) it would help us know what you want to store in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class object for `User` and use that e.g.

```
class User {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    constructor(username: string, password: string) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and your array implementation would look like this

```
  let arr: User[] = new Array();
  arr.push({
      username: "Billy",
      password: "hunter42"
  });
  arr.push(new User("Billy", "hunter42"));
```

You can use both versions, but since you are using typescript you might aswell use the second version by calling the constructor with `new User()`.

Comment: That's what i was looking for and the solution with a class User is also interesting thanks a lot!